# how to navigate from a wpf window to wpf page in C#(3.0)?

Tags: c#, wpf

Hey i'm stucked here from last 3 days and tried as hell of possibilities, I have wpf window called `'Mainwindow.xaml'` i want to navigate  a wpf page named `'addNewTech.xaml'` keeping `'Manwindow.xaml'` open in background please help me out..
 Thank you..

Answer (score 5):

First. Add `Frame` in MainWindow.

For example:

Use this namespace `xmlns:local="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Controls;assembly=PresentationFramework"`

```
<Grid>
   <local:Frame Name="MainFrame" NavigationUIVisibility="Hidden" >                            
   </local:Frame>
</Grid>
```

call `AddNewTech` in `MainWindow.cs` to load page into MainWindow.

```
MainFrame.Navigate(new Uri("addNewTech.xaml",UriKind.Relative));
```

Comment: hey i did as u written,my Mainwindow.xaml have already one Grid i written frame code under that grid, I have written "MainFrame.Navigate(new Uri("addNewTech.xaml",UriKind.Relative));" this code in button_click event on MaimWindow.cs but there nothing happens it can't navigate to 'addNewTech.xmal'....

Comment: Your `addNewTech.xaml` must be in root folder. Otherwise use like this `MainFrame.Navigate(new Uri("foldername/addNewTech.xaml",UriKind.Relative));`

Comment: Please check `Grid width, height!=0` and `addNewTech.xaml` include any visible content.

Comment: addnewTech.xaml has visible content like lable,textbox,Listbox,grid width & height are Auto..

Comment: Good solution, It's a year I wasn't do this stuff and I was forgotten, thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
 NavigationService navService = NavigationService
 .GetNavigationService(this) 

navService.Navigate =  (new
 System.Uri("Page2.xaml",UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);
```

**OR**

```
 Page2 nextPage = new Page2();

 navService.Navigate(nextPage);
```

**OR**

```
 Page2 page2Obj = new Page2(); //Create object of Page2


 page2Obj.Show(); //Show page2 this.Close(); //this will close Page1
```

Comment: The last portion only works with window. There is no Page.show() in native WPF. Also Don't forget that in the second option you still need to create the Nav service object.

Comment: Also .Navigate is a method so the first example won't work because you can't assign to it. You need to call it like you did in the second example.